# Why do my CatBoost fit metrics are different than the sklearn evaluation metrics?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, catboost

I'm still not sure this should be a question for this forum or for Cross-Validated, but I'll try this one, since it's more about the output of the code than the technique per se. Here's the thing, I'm running a CatBoost Classifier, just like this:

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, precision_score, f1_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split    

# import data
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

# get features and label
X = train[["Pclass", "Sex", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare"]]

y = train[["Survived"]]

# split into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

# model parameters 
model_cb = CatBoostClassifier(
    cat_features=["Pclass", "Sex"],
    loss_function="Logloss",
    eval_metric="AUC",
    learning_rate=0.1,
    iterations=500,
    od_type = "Iter",
    od_wait = 200
)

# fit model
model_cb.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    plot=True,
    eval_set=(X_test, y_test),
    verbose=50,
)

y_pred = model_cb.predict(X_test)

print(f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average="macro"))

print(roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

The dataframe I'm using is from the Titanic competition ([link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)).

The problem is that the model_cb.fit step is showing an AUC of 0.87, but the last line, the roc_auc_score from sklearn is showing me an AUC of 0.73, i.e., a much lower. The AUC from CatBoost, from what I understood is supposedly already on the testing dataset.

Any ideas on which is the problem here and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ROC curve needs predicted probabilities or some other sort of confidence measure, not hard class predictions.  Use

```py
y_pred = model_cb.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
```

See [Scikit-learn : roc_auc_score](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30623637/10495893) and [Why does roc_curve return only 3 values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65374015/10495893).